# Retrieve blob from object/embed/iframe that loads a fillable PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, blob

I am able to load a fillable PDF into an object, embed, or iframe tag.  Either of those methods render the PDF fine on the screen.  After the user fills out the PDF, I would like them to click a button (outside of the object/embed/iframe) in which I retrieve the PDF as a blob (using javascript, not jquery) from the element and send it to the server.  The only part I cannot figure out is extracting the edited PDF from the object/embed/iframe.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do let the browser handle the rendering and editing of the pdf through its own plugin, there is little chances you can do anything like that, at least not in a cross-browser way.

There is no standards regarding displaying pdf in a browser. Most will launch a plugin while some (e.g FF based) do have such a viewer built-in.
The ones using a plugin could expose an API through an <embed> tag, though I never saw such thing yet, but anyway, none would expose the same API.

So your best bet here is to not let the browser handle this and rather be in full control.

A library like [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js), developed by Mozilla is a good way to show pdf in a cross-browser way, and to gain access to some settings like document's name, and while I don't know if there is an easy method, you can also very probably export to Blob.

However, [AcroForms are still to get implemented](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7613) in this library, so you won't be able to use it for your purpose.
But note that this also means that your Firefox users won't be able using the native viewer either, since it's actually *pdf.js* in this browser.

Answer (score -1):

a BLOB identifier can be easily identified using the .getBlob functionality or  the default specifier.

Comment: Ummm.. ok...  I don't see how this answers my question.